# Interrupt the bash script with SIGINT

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, c++

Hello I have a bash script that is one liner for executing a piece of long running C++ code. Running `ps -xaf` the script is running and C++ code is its child

```
script.sh
\_ long_main.cpp
```

When i run the code from the command line and press ctrl+C the bash script and the c++ code are interrupted and stop the execution. I love that.

However when i run a script and execute kill -SIGINT PID on my script the script dies, and C++ code runs on. When i run `ps -xaf` i see that sh script is dead indeed, but C++ code is running on its own, and it is now a top level process like so:

```
long_main.cpp
```

Could you please elaborate on what is the difference between CRTL+C and kill -SIGINT  in this case.

Comment: with CTRL-C you kill your application, then the script exits. with kill, you send a signal to the script (and not to your application). So the continue running

Comment: `kill` kills only single processes if you give it a PID, you have to specify a PGID (process group ID) to kill a process and its children, see the question I linked. `pkill` is a convenient way to simplify the task. Also related: [What's the best way to send a signal to all members of a process group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/392022/6164712)

Comment: Read `man 7 signal`

Answer (score 1):

If the shell script in question only contains a single command that invokes an external program you can prepend the command with `exec` to *replace* the shell process instead of spawning a new process. E. g. change

```sh
/path/to/my-program "$@"
```

to

```sh
exec /path/to/my-program "$@"
```

Since `my-program` now replaces the shell process it retains its PID and receives all signals sent to it *by PID* incl. SIGINT. Obviously you can't send a signal to it based on the name or command-line of the shell script any longer.